# Common toggle function doesn't work well with setState()

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a state which represents this interface:

```
StateInterface {
  variableOne: string;
  variableTwo: boolean;
  variableThree: boolean; 
  // ...
}
```

And toggle function:

```
toggleFunction = (value: keyof StateInterface): void => {
  this.setState((state) => ({
    [value]: !state[value]
  }));
};
```

**Not all variables are boolean in my state**

But TSLint is telling me that the function is missing some properties.
Is it possible to use only one toggle function for my state?

Comment: why is variableOne: string; is stirng?

Comment: only some variables are boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but it works:

```
this.setState((state) => ({
  ...state,
  [value]: !state[value],
}));
```

Without `...state` I get an error about missing fields

Answer (score 1):

so what about to make your function to only accpet keys that are boolean in your interface?

```
interface IStateInterface {
  variableOne: string;
  variableTwo: boolean;
  variableThree: boolean;
  // ...
}

// here you make type filtered type
type FilterType<Base, Condition> = {
  [Key in keyof Base]:
  Base[Key] extends Condition ? Key : never
};

// so this is type where all type that don't go throught condition are "never"
type filteredState = FilterType<IStateInterface, boolean>;  

and here just pick the keys
type allowedKeys = filteredState [keyof filteredState];
```

so in your function you have

```
toggleFunction = (value: allowedKeys ): void => {
  this.setState((state) => ({
    [value]: !state[value]
  }));
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=15&ssc=56&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUx0q815LIDeAsAFDKXIBucUwcARgDYQDyIEAXMgM5j0QAcwDc5KjToMWEACoB3APY9GixazggxFKrXpNWsgBZQI3ZKvURN2iQHo7yAHQvyAX3LkwATwAOKADFgZkgoWT8IAB4AITheCAAaZABhRRAAE2AwYDSAPmQAXmJxKgBtAGkIb2RQZABrKsUYZFj4gF0uEspWiAqqtuQIAA9IDN4UtMzstOQAfmRK6p5Oamh3bS8I5Bhg0Ih0zGwUIqCQ6HD-SIwsHDxYRESLNQ0QXJFkTzIff2Q4ZmZFPJ9otxkUdmdTAcbihSg1vE1trtoPtDpA2iIgA)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please more elaborate the query more specifically about what your toggle function will do.

From above toggle function I can see that you are changing the state of a boolean state variable.

What about **variableOne** which is string.

For your case you have to setState conditional based on the value.

> If-else might work to check value is boolean or not.

```
toggleFunction = (value: keyof StateInterface): void => {
   if (typeof variable === "boolean") 
{
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    [value]: !prevState[value]
  }));
} else {
   this.setState((prevState) => ({
    [value]: 'Some value'
  }));
}

};
```

Comment: Only some variables are boolean.
Yes, I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Could you please share some demo code on codepen or anywhere. It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

for `setState` method we have 2 options for using:

In your case, you used function, so which will be mutated only property not for all state's properties.

You can try to use this code:

```
toggleFunction = (value: keyof StateInterface): void => {
  this.setState((state) => {
    value.forEach(property => {
    if( typeof(state[property]) != 'string'){ 
    state[property]= !state[property]
    }
  });
  return state;
};
```